# why will my hopper not move items to the next hopper?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have one hopper connected to the other, and the other to a chest. I know I have them connected correctly, because the second hopper deposits into the chest perfectly.

However, items do not transfer from the first to the second hopper. Why won't this work?

Comment: i copied the design from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fnatRPiDl4 if that helps at all.

Comment: A screenshot would help us the most, but I'll throw some common stuff into an answer and see if it helps, anyway.

Comment: Is there any redstone around the hopper? If a hopper receives a redstone signal it will not output any items.

Answer (score 6):

Is the first hopper targeting the second hopper?  You might have placed the hopper so that the little pipe on bottom isn't pointing at the second hopper.

Is there redstone running near the hoppers?  A hopper receiving a redstone signal doesn't do anything.

Comment: This seems more like clarification questions that should be made as comments more then it does an answer

Comment: @Timelord64 As these are the only two things with a realistic chance of being the problem (outside of mods, anyway), it feels like an answer to me.  The questions are a stylistic choice, to prompt the OP to check those things, troubleshooting-style.  The answer could easily be rewritten as "Check that the first hopper's pipe is pointing to the second hopper and that no redstone signals are running too near the hoppers." to eliminate the question marks, I just feel it's more readable and friendly this way.  If it bothers you enough, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have shift-right clicked the hopper onto the target hopper and nothing is powering it, as powering a hopper will stop it from outputting items.